# How can I check the voltage of a fan?

Tags: voltage, fan

Is there a way I can connect 1 or 2 batteries to a CPU Fan that I dissasembled to check what voltage it is so I can use it at the highest speed?

Comment: You can do so, but these fans run at a speed dependent on their supply voltage, so if you don't have the label or datasheet to tell you what speed it *should* be running at, at a defined supply voltage, you can't know whether you're applying the correct voltage.

Comment: Give us some more details, like whether the fan has 4 wires or 2 wires.

Comment: every CPU fan I've ever used, several dozen, run at the 12v ATX standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run the fan at max speed:

- You can first test for 5V and then 9V. Visually observe the fan and if it is not running fast then go for 12V.
- Do not exceed the 12V limit as most PC fans are rated for max 12V.

Since, there is no label/datasheet it is quite hard to precisely tell at what voltage the fan will achieve the max speed, thus only thing that can be done is trial & error.